# .listing: Permission denied when downloading data via ftp

Tags: permissions, ftp, vsftpd

I have a problem to download data via ftp. I am completely hazy about ftp.

I am trying to get data via `wget 'ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/db/nt*.gz'`

Even though I set anonymous_enable=YES, local_enable=YES
, write_enable=YES in vsftpd.conf, I encounter the error below. Can someone help me how to figure out the error?

Thanks

> --2022-10-24 08:57:21--  ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/db/nt*.gz
> => ‘.listing’ Resolving ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov (ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov)... 130.14.250.13, 165.112.9.228,
> 2607:f220:41f:250::230, ... Connecting to ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov
> (ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov)|130.14.250.13|:21... connected. Logging in as
> anonymous ... Logged in!
> ==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
> ==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD (1) /blast/db ... done.
> ==> PASV ... done.    ==> LIST ... done. .listing: Permission denied

Comment: What ever site you are trying to access they have not given you permission to download. You need to contact them. Not a problem at the local end.

Answer (score 2):

In which directory are you trying to use `wget`? Are you sure you have permission to write to that directory?

When I run `wget ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/db/nt*.gz` (without the quotes) from the Terminal, it downloads several gigabytes just fine. The first item that will be saved, though, is a file called `.listing`, which contains all of the files in the source directory that you are downloading from. If you are trying to use `wget` from a directory where you do not have permission to save files. `.listing` will not be written and the `wget` command will fail with a `.listing: Permission denied` error.

As a test, try this:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open) or connect to the machine that is going to use `wget` via SSH (if not already connected)
1. Make sure you're in the home directory for your account:

   ```
   cd ~
   ```
2. Create a directory for all this data:

   ```
   mkdir nih
   ```
3. Change to that directory:

   ```
   cd nih
   ```
4. Run the `wget` command:

   ```
   wget ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/db/nt*.gz
   ```

You should see something like this:

```
--2022-10-24 06:57:07--  ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/db/nt*.gz
           => ‘.listing’
Resolving ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov (ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov)... 2607:f220:41f:250::229, 2607:f220:41f:250::230, 130.14.250.10, ...
Connecting to ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov (ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov)|2607:f220:41f:250::229|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD (1) /blast/db ... done.
==> EPSV ... done.    ==> LIST ... done.

.listing                                    [    <=>                                                                         ]  70.75K  42.3KB/s    in 1.7s    

2022-10-24 06:57:18 (42.3 KB/s) - ‘.listing’ saved [72451]

Removed ‘.listing’.
--2022-10-24 06:57:18--  ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/db/nt.00.tar.gz
           => ‘nt.00.tar.gz’
==> CWD not required.
==> EPSV ... done.    ==> RETR nt.00.tar.gz ... done.
Length: 4365255023 (4.1G)

nt.00.tar.gz                              2%[>                                                                               ]  96.27M  4.26MB/s    eta 13m 39s
```

Comment: I guess, you are right I didn't have permission to write to my directory because I tried  again with your way and got same error, on the other hand, I used  ftp link with sudo wget and it worked.